# mongoose findMany query with refs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, dataloader

I am new to mongoose I don't really find any reference how mongoose `populate` deals with findMany query having `ref`

for example I have a `categories` collection and a `products` collection as on product can be assigned to many categories that's why they exist in 2 different collections.

Now if I call `findMany` method on `categories` collection and also `populate` with `products` will mongoose execute per category find products ? or all referenced product ids will be collected and in one query all products will be queried like `dataloader` do ?

Answer (score 2):

You should have two schemas, category and product:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  // ...
  categories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema );

const categorySchema = Schema({
  title: String,
  description:String,
  products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema );
```

To find category by id with populated products you could:

```js
app.get('/categories/:id', (req, res) => {

    const categoryId = req.params.id;

    (async () => {
        try {
            const categories = await Categories
                  .find({ _id: categoryId }).populate("products") // you'r populating the property of the schema called products
            res.status(200).json({ results: categories })
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: "Error ..." })
        }
    })()
});
```

Comment: An example provided by Mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html